# New at jQuery, lack of structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

My job required me to learn jQuery the last couple of weeks, but it's a mess and I do not know how to structure my code in an acceptable manner. I come from a Java and PHP background and have never touched JavaScript before.

I've searched the web for some guidelines, but I could not find anything of real value.

```
function answer(id, value) {
    $("input#" + id).val(value);
}

$("table.grid").ready(function() {
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "7.0") {
        var z = 1000;

        $("table, tr, th, td, div").each(function() {
            $(this).css("z-index", z);
            z -= 10;
        });
    }

    $("td[rowspan=2]").parent().addClass("no-border");
    $("td.answer-head").prevAll("td.radio").each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass("answer-tail");
    });
    $("td.radio").click(function() {
        var $that = $(this);
        var $left = $that.prevAll("td.radio").andSelf();
        var $right = $that.nextAll("td.radio");
        var $parent = $that.parent();
        var $cousin = null;

        if ($parent.children().first().attr("rowspan") != undefined) {
            $cousin = $parent.next("tr").children("td.radio").eq($left.length - 1);
        } else if ($parent.prev("tr").children().first().attr("rowspan") != undefined) {
            $cousin = $parent.prev("tr").children("td.radio").eq($left.length - 1);
        }

        if ($cousin !== null) {
            $left = $left.add($cousin).add($cousin.prevAll("td.radio"));
            $right = $right.add($cousin.nextAll("td.radio"));
        }

        $left.each(function(index) {
            var $that = $(this);

            if ($that.hasClass("answer-head")) {
                $that.addClass("click-head");
            } else if ($that.hasClass("answer-tail")) {
                $that.addClass("click-tail");
            } else {
                $that.addClass("click");
            }
        });
        $right.each(function(index) {
            $(this).removeClass("click-head").removeClass("click-tail").removeClass("click");
        });
    }).hover(function() {
        var $that = $(this);
        var $left = $that.prevAll("td.radio").andSelf();
        var $right = $that.nextAll("td.radio");
        var $parent = $that.parent();
        var $cousin = null;

        if ($parent.children().first().attr("rowspan") != undefined) {
            $cousin = $parent.next("tr").children("td.radio").eq($left.length - 1);
        } else if ($parent.prev("tr").children().first().attr("rowspan") != undefined) {
            $cousin = $parent.prev("tr").children("td.radio").eq($left.length - 1);
        }

        if ($cousin !== null) {
            $left = $left.add($cousin).add($cousin.prevAll("td.radio"));
            $right = $right.add($cousin.nextAll("td.radio"));
        }

        var $help = $that.add($cousin).find("div.help").first();
        $help.css("display", "inline-block");

        $left.each(function(index) {
            $that = $(this);

            if ($that.hasClass("answer-head")) {
                $that.addClass("hover-head");
            } else if ($that.hasClass("answer-tail")) {
                $that.addClass("hover-tail");
            } else {
                $that.addClass("hover");
            }
        });
    }, function() {
        var $that = $(this);
        var $all = $that.siblings("td.radio").andSelf();
        var $parent = $that.parent();

        if ($parent.children().first().attr("rowspan") != undefined) {
            $all = $all.add($parent.next("tr").children("td.radio"));
        } else if ($parent.prev("tr").children().first().attr("rowspan") != undefined) {
            $all = $all.add($parent.prev("tr").children("td.radio"));
        }

        $all.find("div.help").css("display", "none");

        $all.each(function(index) {
            $(this).removeClass("hover-head").removeClass("hover-tail").removeClass("hover");
        });
    });
});
```

Above are my hundred lines of code. The script does exactly what I want to do, but it does look ugly, doesn't it? Could you provide a guide/tutorial on how to structure this mess up or give me some pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once you define a group of objects with jquery, you only have to loop through them if you want each one to do something different.

the `each` function actually loops through each item, allowing you do do something different to each object.

for example, you put

```
$all.find("div.help").css("display", "none");

    $all.each(function(index) {
        $(this).removeClass("hover-head").removeClass("hover-tail").removeClass("hover");
    });
```

but while your looping with the `each` function, you are doing the exact same thing to every  object, so the loop is not needed. you can use:

```
$all.find("div.help").css("display", "none").removeClass("hover-head").removeClass("hover-tail").removeClass("hover");
```

and to make it even simpler, with many jquery functions, you can seperate multiple classes and ids with a space and actually shrink all of that code to this

```
$all.find("div.help").css("display", "none").removeClass("hover-head hover-tail hover");
```

and to take it one step further, display none can be achieved with hide() - and  you can display items with show()

```
$all.find("div.help").hide().removeClass("hover-head hover-tail hover");
```

EDIT: TO HELP CLARIFY TO YOUR RESPONSE

you can try this, its hard for me to test without all of your working code.

```
$("td.radio").click(function() {
    var $that = $(this);

    doStuff($that,'click');
    $that.nextAll("td.radio").removeClass("click-head click-tail click");   

}).hover(function() {
    var $that = $(this);

    doStuff($that, 'hover');
    var $help = $that.add($cousin).find("div.help").first();
    $help.css("display", "inline-block");


}
// rest of your code
```

then add this function

```
function doStuff(eL , which){
        var $that=$(eL);
        var $left = $that.prevAll("td.radio").andSelf();
        var $right = $that.nextAll("td.radio");
        var $parent = $that.parent();
        var $cousin = null;

        if ($parent.children().first().attr("rowspan") != undefined) {
            $cousin = $parent.next("tr").children("td.radio").eq($left.length - 1);
        } else if ($parent.prev("tr").children().first().attr("rowspan") != undefined) {
            $cousin = $parent.prev("tr").children("td.radio").eq($left.length - 1);
        }

        if ($cousin !== null) {
            $left = $left.add($cousin).add($cousin.prevAll("td.radio"));
            $right = $right.add($cousin.nextAll("td.radio"));
        }

        $left.each(function(index) {
            var $that = $(this);

            if ($that.hasClass("answer-head")) {
                $that.addClass( which + "-head");
            } else if ($that.hasClass("answer-tail")) {
                $that.addClass( which + "-tail");
            } else {
                $that.addClass( which );
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I will definitely make changes regarding that, but I'm also thinking about the overall structure. I have a bit of duplicated code in `.click()` and `.hover()`. How would I go about defining a function which returns `$left`, `$right` and in some cases `$cousin` following the jQuery style?

Comment: i wouldnt return the values like your asking. i would write the function to perform the things you want done.see my edit.

Comment: Thank you again. I will show my refactored version tomorrow and see if it's any better. :)